# How do I properly output a string for a YAML file that includes a "#"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, utf-8, yaml

I'm using Django 3 and Python 3.7.  I'm trying to write a function that will output properly formatted YAML.  I have this ...

```
def strip_invalid(s):
    res = ''
    for x in s:
        if Reader.NON_PRINTABLE.match(x):
            # res += '\\x{:x}'.format(ord(x))
            continue
        res += x
    return res
...
yaml_street = load(strip_invalid(street.strip().encode("utf-8", 'ignore').decode("utf-8")))
```

The problem is, if "street" is "55 E JACKSON BLVD # 150" the above outputs

```
55 E JACKSON BLVD
```

Note that everything after and including the "#" was removed.  How can I adjust the above so that everything is included but perhaps escaped properly for YAML output?

Comment: Show us the YAML.

Comment: What is `load`? What is `strip_invalid` supposed to produce, a file name, a valid YAML string?

Comment: @chepner, yes the function should produce a valid YAML string, removing any non-UTF-8 characters (or at least making all characters UTF-8 safe)

Comment: Sorry if I am thinking "out loud" here: it seems, from your comment below, that you either have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where your misconception of what `yaml.load` does, led you to write that whole `strip_invalid` function that should not be in the first place. **Either** you are making this as an exercise/challenge for your own understanding of YAML, and then you should maybe provide us where the `load` function is coming from and its code if you write it yourself.

Comment: Maybe you can clear that by explaining your own understanding of what `yaml = load('sting')` does here.

Answer (score 4):

What you probably intended to do was to use `dump` and not `load`.

> `dump(data, stream=None)` serializes the given Python object into the stream. If stream is None, it returns the produced stream.

<sup>*Source: https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#reference*</sup>

```py
from yaml import dump
print(dump({'foo': 'bar # with hash'}))
```

Outputs:

> ```yaml
> foo: 'bar # with hash'
> ```

So your whole code would end up being:

```py
from yaml import dump
street = '  55 E JACKSON BLVD # 150  '
yaml_street = dump(street.strip())
print(yaml_street)
```

Outputs:

> '55 E JACKSON BLVD # 150'

---

If you insist on writing your own function, though, this happens because the hash `#` is actually a comment in YAML

```yaml
foo: I am a string until the hash # and then I am a comment
```

To avoid this, you can [quote your string](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761245):

```yaml
foo: 'I am a string until the second quote # even if there is a hash'
```

Also note that escaping an existing quote `'` in YAML is just about doubling it.

```yaml
foo: 'Don't us me I am a broken YAML construct'
```

Would be resolved by

```yaml
foo: 'I''m able to fit quote in a YAML string by doubling it'
```

So you could go by:

```py
def strip_invalid(s):
    res = ''
    for x in s:
        if Reader.NON_PRINTABLE.match(x):
            # res += '\\x{:x}'.format(ord(x))
            continue
        res += x
    return "'{}'".format(res.replace("'","''"))

yaml_street = strip_invalid(street.strip().encode("utf-8", 'ignore').decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Thanks -- I tried your second solution and ran into a hiccup.  If my string is '41°47'49"N 87°35'29"W', the code 'load(Command.strip_invalid(row['address'].strip().encode("utf-8", 'ignore').decode("utf-8")))' dies with the error, "yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<scalar>', in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 20:, '4''1''°''4''7'''''4''9''"''N'' ''8''7''°''3''5'''' ... ".

Comment: Because you keep using `load` when you should be using `dump`. `load` takes a *stream* from which you can read a YAML document and decode it.

Comment: As pointed out by @chepner `load` might be part of your issue. This said, escaping a quote in YAML means doubling it.

Comment: For some reason I thought you had "load" in your solution.  Anyway I replaced "load" with "dump" and changed the strip_invalid to what you have, but it is still producing strange output.  For example, "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza" is getting translated to something that begins with "'''2''''2''''2'''' ''''W''''.'''' ''''M''''e''''r''''c''''h''''a''''n''''d''''i''''s''''e'''' ..."

Comment: Oh, my! You are looping on every char in the string in that function...

Comment: But really, @Dave that function should not be there **at all** `dump()` will take care of those supposed invalid characters already.